# Send Invoice to email using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm not doing so well with the English grammar, but I hope someone understands me.

I want to create and send an invoice using input.
Like a register page with email key confirmation .

Example.

I have invoiceinformation.php

```
<script><?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['invoice'] = $invoice;
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;
$_SESSION['city'] = $city;
$_SESSION['state'] = $state;
$_SESSION['zip'] = $zip;



?></script>
<html>
<h3 align="center">Invoice Information</H3>
<form align="center" method="get" action="**Auto create by invoice value**">
    <input type="text" name="invoice" value="" placeholder="Invoice#"><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Buyer Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" value="" placeholder="Address"><br>
    <input type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder="City"><br>
    <input type="text" name="state" value="" placeholder="State"><br>
    <input type="text" name="zip" value="" placeholder="Zip Code"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

In that "**Auto create by invoice value**" I want to put this,

```
<?php

session_start();
$invoice = $_GET['invoice'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$city = $_GET['city'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
$zip = $_GET['zip'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
      <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" />
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <title><?php echo $invoice; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<small><font size="2" color="#999999" face="verdana,
            sans-serif"><b><span class=""> sent this invoice to


            <br><?php echo $name; ?><br>


            Your registered name is included to show this invoice from Company</b></font>

<span>Your address is : <?php echo $address; ?>
<span>Your City is : <?php echo $city; ?>
<span>Your Zip Code is : <?php echo $zip; ?>
<span>Your State is : <?php echo $state; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And after that I want to create `<?php echo $invoice; ?>`.php with "Auto create by invoice value" source code.

After that I want to send an email but I will need a letter for email, like this:

letter.php

```
<h3>Thanks for using company ! <br>Here's your invoice.<br></h3>

<a href="https://example.com/<?php echo $invoice; ?>.php" >View Invoice</a>
```

Or much easier ... if I can of course!

Comment: `action="**Auto create by invoice value**"` - `action` value should be a file name.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i dont know what is "Auto create by invoice value" .
but i could provide you with some information.

assuming you have 3 page & u have no databases:

1. invoiceinformation.php
2. AutoCreate.php
3. letter.php

which

1. invoiceinformation.php is gather the value form user using form and send all those value to AutoCreate.php
2. AutoCreate.php is displaying all those value from user input and to comfirm the user if those input is correct, if there is an incorrect input, it will redirect to invoiceinformation.php page and user reinput those incorrect input
3. Letter.php is to retrieve the information and notify the user that you will send email to their respective email address.

its easy, you dont need those session in invoiceinformation.php instead to set those session in AutoCreate.php

```
$to = $_SESSION['email'];
$subject = "Invoice";
$txt = "Hello world!"; //this is the body text u can put ur invoice here
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" . // this is your site email & user email (CC)
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Comment: I understand , but I want to create in public_html after I submit the input a file like this , `<?php echo $invoice; ?>`.php  so I can send in email a button with this link , https://example.com/`<?php echo $invoice; ?>`.php                   LIKE: `<a href="example.com/<?php echo $invoice;?>>View Invoice</a>`